# spring-boot how to get a full wsdl file

Tags: spring-boot

I have my WSDL file and I have this spring-boot configuration for exposing my service

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
@Import({CommonConfiguration.class})
public class MyServiceConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    private SpringBus springBus;

    public MyService getMyService() {
        return new MyService()
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> dispatcherServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CXFServlet());
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPathProvider() {
        return () -> "";
    }

    @Bean(name = "myService")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/my_service/myService.wsdl"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus, getMyService());
        endpoint.publish("/services/myService");
        return endpoint;
    }

}
```

What I expect is that when my spring-boot application loads up I can navigate to, i.e.,
https://localhost/?wsdl and my full wsdl file is shown in a browser window. But what I see
is some strange window that looks like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YehJu.png)

and when I click to the link next to WSDL: I get redirected to a wsdl file which is not my
real wsdl file and it looks like this

```
<...>
    <wsdl:import location="https://localhost:7777/services/myService?wsdl=MyService.wsdl"> </wsdl:import>
    <wsdl:binding name="MyServiceServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:MyService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="AckMessage">
            <soap:operation soapAction="AckMessage" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="AckMessage">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="AckMessageResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="MyServiceService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:MyServiceServiceSoapBinding" name="MyServicePort">
            <soap:address location="https://localhost:7777/services/myService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My real wsdl is located here https://localhost:7777/services/myService?wsdl=MyService.wsdl (inside this small wsdl file)

My questions

1. I need to get my real wsdl file when I type ?wsdl and not some random window or a short version
   of wsdl where the real wsdl is referenced as an import. Why I'm not getting my full wsdl? What am I doing wrong? How to fix this situation?

I expect to get my real full wsdl when I type in url bar https://localhost:7777/?wsdl and not some window or a short version of wsdl where my real wsdl is referenced as an import.

Answer (score 0):

After half a day of a good luck. I managed to discover that it is possible
to have almost original wsdl by adding

@WebService() annotation on a service you implement. But it is important to fill
all fields in that annotation as well as add a location of wsdl, i.e.,

```
@WebService(
        name = "myService",
        targetNamespace = "myService",
        serviceName = "myService",
        portName = "myService",
        wsdlLocation = "classpath:wsdl/path/to/my_service.wsdl"
)
public class MyService implements MyService {
}
```

Sure the are small discrepancies between original, i.e., attributes are misplaced, namespace definitions are misplaced and some new namespaces are added, but this solution preserves documentation tags (wsdl:documentation my notes </wsdl:documentation>), but it fails to preserve comments such as .